# OpenCV error while converting image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I am trying to import a picture of size (540,960) using matplotlib.
This step is successfully executed. The result is stored in 'image' object (type ndarray).

```
# Do relevant imports
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Read in and grayscale the image
image = mpimg.imread(r'C:\Temp\pic24_bw.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

But when I try to convert the image into another color space (Gray), using cv2.cvtColor(). I face a error:

```
error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111:        error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor
```

Please help. Strange thing is this code is running successfully in another citrix environment.

Comment: Check `print(type(image));print(image.dtype, image.shape)`

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me, load/read your image through cv2 itself and please do recheck your image path as it is the most common mistake, we does.

```
import numpy as np               
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
%matplotlib inline    
#reading the image 
image = cv2.imread('cat.jpg')
image = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#plotting the image
plt.imshow(image)
```

Hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

I tried plt.imshow. The image is successfully loaded. It is shown in a RGB scale.

```
image = mpimg.imread(r'C:\Temp\pic24_bw.jpg') 
plt.imshow(image,cmap='gray')
```

Comment: maybe plt uses another channel ordering than opencv? Did you try cv2.imread to load the image?

Answer (score 0):

This error message appears when the image could not be loaded, or it has an incorrect number of channels (cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY needs an image with 3 or 4 channels).

1. You have to use `cv2.imread()` instead of `mpimg.imread()`
2. If you still have errors, try `print(image.shape)`. Most likely, the image does not have three channels.

You can also try viewing the image with:

```
cv2.imshow("Test", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```